# File reader API gives no out put on AUDIO files

Tags: javascript, html5-video, html5-audio, filereader, html5-img

As a part of a *before upload* control, I check if added files actually match the filetype that their extension describes.

I do a filecheck using a hidden element. and if it fails, it gets removed after `formdata` append.

I check the files at the backend too, but I also want to check via File Reader process. All functions like `createItems` or `readItems` and so on, are working in all other cases, meaning that they return output of either **null**, **true** or **false**. While I get output from image and video files, audio files not at all. It should work.

The question is: 
**Does the file reader read `audio` files differently compared to `video` and `image` files?**

The following is only a tiny block of the actual code.
Now the question is: **Why it doesn't return output on audio files?**.

- `quest0` & `quest1` are UI elements. Which is the element that I pull the files from.
- `reader` is "new FileReader".
- `what.filecount` is added while page init as readonly property.
- `readItems` gives output on all kind off files,

However the UI html doesn't get updated if it is the file type is `audio/`?

```
for (var oD = 0; oD < what.files.length; oD++) 
{
    var pL = false;
    if (typeof window.dofile === 'undefined' || !window.dofile) { return; }
    
    if (file_s.exec(file) && !what.multiple) { pL = true; }
    else 
    {
        if (what.files.length > what.filecount) 
        {
            alert('too many files added. only ' + what.filecount + ' are allowed.');
            what.value = '';
            
            if (quest0 != null) 
            { quest0.innerHTML = ('too many files added. only ' + what.filecount + ' are allowed.'); }
            
            return;
        }
        
        pL = true;
        if ( !lastform.includes(what.form.id) ) { pL = false; }
    }
    
    if (what.files && what.files[oD] && pL == true) 
    {
        if (file_prev != null) 
        {
            if (file_prev.getAttribute('data-src') == '') 
            {file_prev.setAttribute('data-src', file_prev.src); }
            
            file_prev.src = file_backsrc;
        }
        
        reader.onload = function(e) 
        {
            init();
            
            if (typeof file_prev === 'undefined') 
            {
                if (quest1 != null) { quest1.innerHTML = 'Error occoured'; }
                return;
            }
            
            if (file_p == 'img' || file_p == 'video' || file_p == 'audio') 
            { file_prev.src = e.target.result; }
            
            if (file_p == 'canvas') { /*not yet*/ }
            
            kill.classList.remove('invisible');
            
            if (quest1 != null) { quest1.innerHTML = 'file done'; }
        }
        
        reader.onerror = function(e) 
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('There was an error with one of your file(s). Filename ' + what.files[oD].name + '');
            what.value = '';
        }

        function waitfor(arr) 
        {
            if (arr == null || arr.length == 0) { return; }
           
            var aL = arr.length,
                aL0 = arr.shift();
           
            file_prev = _(aL0.file_prev);
            lastfile = aL0.lastfile;
            file_p = aL0.file_p;

            reader.readAsDataURL(aL0.file);
            aL0.kill.classList.add('invisible');
            setTimeout(() => {
                                init();
                                waitfor(arr)
                             }, 1250);
            
            if (quest1 != null) 
            { quest1.innerHTML = 'processing ' + file_p; }
        }
        
        if (what.multiple) 
        {
            var oA = 0;
            lastfile = what.files[oD].name;
            
            for (oA; oA < dK.children.length; oA++) 
            {
                var oB = what.files[oD], oB0, oB1;
                    
                if (oB.type.includes('im')) { file_p = 'img'; }
                if (oB.type.includes('au')) { file_p = 'audio'; }
                if (oB.type.includes('vi')) { file_p = 'video'; }
                
                if (lastfile != what.files[oD].name || lastfilearr.length <= what.filecount) 
                {
                    oB0 = dK.children[oA];
                    if (oB0.nodeName.toLowerCase() == file_p && what.form.querySelectorAll(file_p)[oD] != null)
                    {
                        if ( /*oB0.getAttribute('data-src')==''&&*/ !lastfilearr.includes(what.files[oD].name)) 
                        {
                            oB0 = what.form.querySelectorAll(file_p)[oD];
                            file_prev = oB0;
                            lastfilearr.push(what.files[oD].name);
                            oB0.setAttribute('data-src', lastfile);
                            
                            oB1 = new Object({
                                                'file_prev': file_prev.id,
                                                'file_p': file_p,
                                                'file': what.files[oD],
                                                'kill': kill
                                            });
                            
                            stoargearr.push(oB1);
                            createtoast(['Filechecker', 'the ' + what.files[oD].name + ' is getting checked.', 3e3, true, true, ['bg-info', 'text-dark', 'rounded', 'px-2', 'mx-1']]);
                            createItems('upload', 's', what.files[oD].name, 'name:' + what.files[oD].name + ';nr:' + oD + ';filesize:' + what.files[oD].size + ';filesizehuman:' + Math.abs(what.files[oD].size / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2) + ';lastmodified:' + new Date(what.files[oD].lastModified).toUTCString() + ';type:' + what.files[oD].type + ';');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            if (stoargearr.length == what.files.length) { waitfor(stoargearr); }
            else { reader.readAsDataURL(what.files[oD]); }
        }
    }
}
```

Does the "File reader API" react different on audio files as it does on video or image files?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You should consider running this code through a formatter before posting it here.  Even if you can read it, most programmers cannot.

Answer (score 0):

here it goes.

````
for (var oD = 0; oD < what.files.length; oD++) {
    var pL = false;
    if (typeof window.dofile === 'undefined' || !window.dofile) {
        return;
    };
    if (file_s.exec(file) && !what.multiple) {
        pL = true;
    } else {
        if (what.files.length > what.filecount) {
            alert('too many files added. only ' + what.filecount + ' are allowed.');
            what.value = '';
            if (quest0 != null) {
                quest0.innerHTML = 'too many files added. only ' + what.filecount + ' are allowed.';
            };
            return;
        };
        pL = true;
        if (!lastform.includes(what.form.id)) {
            pL = false;
        };
    };
    if (what.files && what.files[oD] && pL == true) {
        if (file_prev != null) {
            if (file_prev.getAttribute('data-src') == '') {
                file_prev.setAttribute('data-src', file_prev.src);
            };
            file_prev.src = file_backsrc;
        };
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            init();
            if (typeof file_prev === 'undefined') {
                if (quest1 != null) {
                    quest1.innerHTML = 'Error occoured';
                };
                return;
            };
            if (file_p == 'img' || file_p == 'video' || file_p == 'audio') {
                file_prev.src = e.target.result;
            };
            if (file_p == 'canvas') { /*not yet*/ };
            kill.classList.remove('invisible');
            if (quest1 != null) {
                quest1.innerHTML = 'file done';
            };
        };
        reader.onerror = function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('There was an error with one of your file(s). Filename ' + what.files[oD].name + '');
            what.value = '';
        };

        function waitfor(arr) {
            if (arr == null || arr.length == 0) {
                return;
            };
            var aL = arr.length,
                aL0 = arr.shift();
            file_prev = _(aL0.file_prev);
            lastfile = aL0.lastfile;
            file_p = aL0.file_p;
            reader.readAsDataURL(aL0.file);
            aL0.kill.classList.add('invisible');
            setTimeout(() => {
                init();
                waitfor(arr)
            }, 1250);
            if (quest1 != null) {
                quest1.innerHTML = 'processing ' + file_p;
            };
        };
        if (what.multiple) {
            var oA = 0;
            lastfile = what.files[oD].name;
            for (oA; oA < dK.children.length; oA++) {
                var oB = what.files[oD],
                    oB0, oB1;
                if (oB.type.includes('im')) {
                    file_p = 'img';
                };
                if (oB.type.includes('au')) {
                    file_p = 'audio';
                };
                if (oB.type.includes('vi')) {
                    file_p = 'video';
                };
                if (lastfile != what.files[oD].name || lastfilearr.length <= what.filecount) {
                    oB0 = dK.children[oA];
                    if (oB0.nodeName.toLowerCase() == file_p && what.form.querySelectorAll(file_p)[oD] != null) {
                        if ( /*oB0.getAttribute('data-src')==''&&*/ !lastfilearr.includes(what.files[oD].name)) {
                            oB0 = what.form.querySelectorAll(file_p)[oD];
                            file_prev = oB0;
                            lastfilearr.push(what.files[oD].name);
                            oB0.setAttribute('data-src', lastfile);
                            oB1 = new Object({
                                'file_prev': file_prev.id,
                                'file_p': file_p,
                                'file': what.files[oD],
                                'kill': kill
                            });
                            stoargearr.push(oB1);
                            createtoast(['Filechecker', 'the ' + what.files[oD].name + ' is getting checked.', 3e3, true, true, ['bg-info', 'text-dark', 'rounded', 'px-2', 'mx-1']]);
                            createItems('upload', 's', what.files[oD].name, 'name:' + what.files[oD].name + ';nr:' + oD + ';filesize:' + what.files[oD].size + ';filesizehuman:' + Math.abs(what.files[oD].size / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2) + ';lastmodified:' + new Date(what.files[oD].lastModified).toUTCString() + ';type:' + what.files[oD].type + ';');
                        };
                    };
                };
            };
            if (stoargearr.length == what.files.length) {
                waitfor(stoargearr);
            };
        } else {
            reader.readAsDataURL(what.files[oD]);
        };
    };
};```
````

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'll try with what.dataset.src instead, and see if it helps. I come back later and share this answer. But I'm not sure if it actually matters.

Comment: I like to keep the as informative for the user as possible. The question is, does the file reader read files different the video and image files.

Comment: why do i don't get any statements back for this loop , when audio files are added? in this form u may add up 5 video's , image's ('even mixed) and some music, for a kind f collage prensentation. for image and video files i get a feedback, nt for not the audio files added. Why? it's the same form

Comment: I'm sorry, posted a loop from an import, i got it fixed, it was a simple comma misplced error. i

Comment: sorry, my fault. i try to investigate a little bit more nest time i post stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (quest1 != null) {
                quest1.innerHTML = 'processing ' + file_p;
            };
```

This block gives no output on audio files.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).